# How to implement the remove method in the Iterator class for a stack?

Tags: java, iterator, stack, inner-classes

I'm writing an ArrayStack class that uses an iterator. I know using an iterator for a stack doesn't necessarily make sense but this is for homework purposes. I am having trouble with the remove method. I understand its description but I'm having trouble implementing it. Here is the inner class of my program:

```
    private class StackIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
        private int index;
        private boolean canremove;

        public StackIterator() {
            index = size - 1;
            canremove = false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            return index > 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Item next()
        {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("There is no next element"+
                " in the stack.");
            }
            canremove = true;
            return contents[--index];
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            if (!canremove) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Can only remove an element"
                + "after a call to the next method has been made.");
            }
            canremove = false;

        }
}
```

How do I actually go about removing the element? Do I just decrease size? Or do I need more variables to keep track? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Presumably you'd need to shift all the contents of the array past that element back one space.  Or you could just not support it.

Comment: I also think you should get rid of `canremove`.  Probably just check if index >= 0 and index < size, that should be enough given the rest of your code.

Comment: did you want the complete implementation class for this Scenario ?? @Clarisa

Comment: @VikrantKashyap not sure what you mean by that, but I already have the ArrayStack outer class that implements Stack, I just wanted help on the remove() method of the iterator interface for an arraystack